# Robot Framework: using if/else conditions without using keywords

Tags: if-statement, robotframework, keyword, built-in

In the BuiltIn library, there are a ton of "Run keyword If.." commands, but I don't want to test a condition and then run a keyword. Is it possible to use the conditional "if" or "else" without involving keywords?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What's the point of doing an "if" if  you don't do something depending on the condition? What are you actually trying to do? Can you create a [mcve] that illustrates what you're wanting to accomplish?

Comment: I'm testing data to see if a value is set to "yes" or "no". I have an If/Then block that will click a radio button depending upon the value. I don't need to call I keyword, I just need to click the button. The code below isn't valid RF syntax, but it's what I'm trying to do:

`IF  ${PO_Dictionary.ExistingMember}  ==  Yes
    Click Element  ${EXISTING_MEMBER_YES_RADIO}
ELSE
     Click Element  ${EXISTING_MEMBER_NO_RADIO}
     Input Text  ${ZIP_TEXT}  ${PO_Dictionary.ZipCode}
END IF`

Comment: _" I have an If/Then block that will click a radio button depending upon the value. I don't need to call I keyword, I just need to click the button."_ how are you going to click a button if you don't call a keyword? `click element` is a keyword.

Comment: It seems odd to be doing keywords all over the place. I just have a couple lines of code to run. I guess my background is with Java, Python, etc. Seems odd to be calling these keywords every time I want to condition on my data

Comment: _"It seems odd to be doing keywords all over the place. "_ why is it odd? That's precisely what robot framework is designed to do. It's a _keyword driven_ testing framework. Everything you do is with keywords. Robot is not a programming language, it is a framework for running keywords. Even `run keyword if` is itself a keyword.

Answer (score 3):

It appears you misunderstand how robot works. Everything you do in robot is with keywords. Robot framework isn't a programming language, it's a *keyword driven* framework. Its only purpose is to run keywords.

If you want to run `click element` based on a condition, you do it with `run keyword if` since `click element` is itself a keyword.

For example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Examples
    Run keyword if  '${PO_Dictionary.ExistingMember}' == 'Yes'
    ...  Click Element  ${EXISTING_MEMBER_YES_RADIO}
    ...  ELSE
    ...  Click Element ${EXISTING_MEMBER_NO_RADIO}
```

Unfortunately, running multiple commands in an if statement is difficult. If you only want to run `Input Text ${ZIP_TEXT} ${PO_Dictionary.ZipCode}` in the else clause, you have to either call `run keywords` or create a small keyword.

For example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Examples
    run keyword if  '${PO_Dictionary.ExistingMember}' == 'Yes'
    ...  Click Element  ${EXISTING_MEMBER_YES_RADIO}
    ...  ELSE  Run keywords
    ...  Click Element ${EXISTING_MEMBER_NO_RADIO}
    ...  AND  Input Text ${ZIP_TEXT} ${PO_Dictionary.ZipCode}
```